How do I use Coursier credentials with an environment variable?
I'm using bazel to pull artifacts from jfrog. Under the hood it uses Coursier. I've been able to do this just fine with the credentials file:
simple.username=un
simple.password=pwd
simple.host=com.domain.dev
simple.realm=Artifactory Realm

I need to pass these into a docker container as environment variables so the credentials aren't in the image. The Coursier website says you can do this via COURSIER_CREDENTIALS. The guide isn't clear about how to format this.
I've removed the credentials file and am just doing this from the command prompt using the build process locally which works just fine when using the credentials file. I've tried
export COURSIER_CREDENTIALS="com.domain.dev un:pw"
export COURSIER_CREDENTIALS="com.domain.dev(Artifactory Realm) un:pw"
export COURSIER_CREDENTIALS="com.domain.dev(Artifactory) un:pw"
export COURSIER_CREDENTIALS="com.domain.dev(realm) un:pw"

The credentials are fine because when I flip back to the file everything works. Its just a problem with using the env variables.

How are you passing the environment variables into the container?
